# How to split the value of an text-field into an array containing every single char, and than accessing this array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, loops

I would like to split the value of a text field in each character and replace each value of the array thereby incurred by the equivalent in another array. The value in the text field can always be of different lengths. But how can I do that? Do I have to create a new array?

for example:

if the value of text field is: AaBbCc

the new Array should contain: A,a,B,b,C,c

```
var charsv = new Array();
charsv[" "] = 128; charsv["!"] = 01; charsv['"'] = 02; charsv["#"] = 03;     
charsv["$"] = 04; charsv["%"] = 05; charsv["&"] = 06; charsv["’"] = 07;
charsv["("] = 08; charsv[")"] = 09; charsv["*"] = 10; charsv["+"] = 11; 
charsv[","] = 12; charsv["-"] = 13; charsv["."] = 14; charsv["/"] = 15; 
charsv["0"] = 16; charsv["1"] = 17; charsv["2"] = 18; charsv["3"] = 19;
charsv["4"] = 20; charsv["5"] = 21; charsv["6"] = 22; charsv["7"] = 23; 
charsv["8"] = 24; charsv["9"] = 25; charsv[":"] = 26; charsv[";"] = 27; 
charsv["<"] = 28; charsv["="] = 29; charsv[">"] = 30; charsv["?"] = 31; 
charsv["@"] = 32; charsv["A"] = 33; charsv["B"] = 34; charsv["C"] = 35; 
charsv["D"] = 36; charsv["E"] = 37; charsv["F"] = 38; charsv["G"] = 39;
charsv["H"] = 40; charsv["I"] = 41; charsv["J"] = 42; charsv["K"] = 43; 
charsv["L"] = 44; charsv["M"] = 45; charsv["N"] = 46; charsv["O"] = 47; 
charsv["P"] = 48; charsv["Q"] = 49; charsv["R"] = 50; charsv["S"] = 51; 
charsv["T"] = 52; charsv["U"] = 53; charsv["V"] = 54; charsv["W"] = 55; 
charsv["X"] = 56; charsv["Y"] = 57; charsv["Z"] = 58; charsv["["] = 59; 
charsv["\\"] = 60; charsv["]"] = 61; charsv["^"] = 62; charsv["_"] = 63; 
charsv["`"] = 64; charsv["a"] = 65; charsv["b"] = 66; charsv["c"] = 67; 
charsv["d"] = 68; charsv["e"] = 69; charsv["f"] = 70; charsv["g"] = 71; 
charsv["h"] = 72; charsv["i"] = 73; charsv["j"] = 74; charsv["k"] = 75; 
charsv["l"] = 76; charsv["m"] = 77; charsv["n"] = 78; charsv["o"] = 79; 
charsv["p"] = 80; charsv["q"] = 81; charsv["r"] = 82; charsv["s"] = 83;  
charsv["t"] = 84; charsv["u"] = 85; charsv["v"] = 86; charsv["w"] = 87; 
charsv["x"] = 88; charsv["y"] = 89; charsv["z"] = 90; charsv["{"] = 91; 
charsv["|"] = 92; charsv["}"] = 93; charsv["~"] = 94; charsv["•"] = 99; 
charsv["š"] = 104; charsv["œ"] = 106;
```

the result should be: 33,65,34,66,35,67

Comment: Ok I'm sorry if this bothers you, but you really shouldn't use an Array as a map, you should use an object, it's faster, or learn to use ES6 Maps: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function and pass it empty string as a parameter

```
var text = "asdfghj";
var arr = text.split(""); // returns ["a", "s", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j"]
```

Then to convert each character into it's char code, you can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for this

```
arr.map(function (char) { return char.charCodeAt(0); }); 
// returns [97, 115, 100, 102, 103, 104, 106]
```

EDIT: I noticed your `charsv` array doesn't map each character to it's ASCII code. However, even in this case you can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
arr.map(function (char) { return charsv[char]; }); 
// returns [65, 83, 68, 70, 71, 72, 74]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick help, your solution is working fine for me.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick help, your solution is working fine for me. But can you help me again? What i have to do if i wish to create an variable where the single values from arr multiplied with their position in arr? For example (65*1,  83*2 ,68*3 , 70*4, 71*5, 72*6, 74*7) and these new values are added to a sum? (65*1 +  83*2  + 68*3  + 70*4 + 71*5 + 72*6 + 74*7)

Comment: The second parameter for the callback functin in `map` is index. You can use that: `arr.map(function (char, i) { return charsv[char] * (i + 1); });`. To sum the values, take the newly generated array and sum up all values `var sum = 0; for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; arr++) { sum +=  arr[i]; }`. Alternatively, for summing you can use reduce `arr.reduce(function (prev, cur) { return prev + cur; });`. Here's the documentation to the reduce function https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Answer (score 1):

`split` the string and iterate through the `charsv` keys.

```js
var charsv = new Array();
charsv[" "] = 128; charsv["!"] = 01; charsv['"'] = 02; charsv["#"] = 03;     
charsv["$"] = 04; charsv["%"] = 05; charsv["&"] = 06; charsv["’"] = 07;
charsv["("] = 08; charsv[")"] = 09; charsv["*"] = 10; charsv["+"] = 11; 
charsv[","] = 12; charsv["-"] = 13; charsv["."] = 14; charsv["/"] = 15; 
charsv["0"] = 16; charsv["1"] = 17; charsv["2"] = 18; charsv["3"] = 19;
charsv["4"] = 20; charsv["5"] = 21; charsv["6"] = 22; charsv["7"] = 23; 
charsv["8"] = 24; charsv["9"] = 25; charsv[":"] = 26; charsv[";"] = 27; 
charsv["<"] = 28; charsv["="] = 29; charsv[">"] = 30; charsv["?"] = 31; 
charsv["@"] = 32; charsv["A"] = 33; charsv["B"] = 34; charsv["C"] = 35; 
charsv["D"] = 36; charsv["E"] = 37; charsv["F"] = 38; charsv["G"] = 39;
charsv["H"] = 40; charsv["I"] = 41; charsv["J"] = 42; charsv["K"] = 43; 
charsv["L"] = 44; charsv["M"] = 45; charsv["N"] = 46; charsv["O"] = 47; 
charsv["P"] = 48; charsv["Q"] = 49; charsv["R"] = 50; charsv["S"] = 51; 
charsv["T"] = 52; charsv["U"] = 53; charsv["V"] = 54; charsv["W"] = 55; 
charsv["X"] = 56; charsv["Y"] = 57; charsv["Z"] = 58; charsv["["] = 59; 
charsv["\\"] = 60; charsv["]"] = 61; charsv["^"] = 62; charsv["_"] = 63; 
charsv["`"] = 64; charsv["a"] = 65; charsv["b"] = 66; charsv["c"] = 67; 
charsv["d"] = 68; charsv["e"] = 69; charsv["f"] = 70; charsv["g"] = 71; 
charsv["h"] = 72; charsv["i"] = 73; charsv["j"] = 74; charsv["k"] = 75; 
charsv["l"] = 76; charsv["m"] = 77; charsv["n"] = 78; charsv["o"] = 79; 
charsv["p"] = 80; charsv["q"] = 81; charsv["r"] = 82; charsv["s"] = 83;  
charsv["t"] = 84; charsv["u"] = 85; charsv["v"] = 86; charsv["w"] = 87; 
charsv["x"] = 88; charsv["y"] = 89; charsv["z"] = 90; charsv["{"] = 91; 
charsv["|"] = 92; charsv["}"] = 93; charsv["~"] = 94; charsv["•"] = 99; 
charsv["š"] = 104; charsv["œ"] = 106;

var input = document.getElementById('input');
var output = document.getElementById('output');

function lookup(event) {
  var s = input.value.split('');
  var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
     result.push(charsv[s[i]]);
    }
    output.innerHTML = s.join(',') + '<br>' + result.join(',');
}
input.onkeyup = lookup;
lookup();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" value="AaBbCc">
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var charsv = new Array();
charsv[" "] = 128; charsv["!"] = 01; charsv['"'] = 02; charsv["#"] = 03;     
charsv["$"] = 04; charsv["%"] = 05; charsv["&"] = 06; charsv["’"] = 07;
charsv["("] = 08; charsv[")"] = 09; charsv["*"] = 10; charsv["+"] = 11; 
charsv[","] = 12; charsv["-"] = 13; charsv["."] = 14; charsv["/"] = 15; 
charsv["0"] = 16; charsv["1"] = 17; charsv["2"] = 18; charsv["3"] = 19;
charsv["4"] = 20; charsv["5"] = 21; charsv["6"] = 22; charsv["7"] = 23; 
charsv["8"] = 24; charsv["9"] = 25; charsv[":"] = 26; charsv[";"] = 27; 
charsv["<"] = 28; charsv["="] = 29; charsv[">"] = 30; charsv["?"] = 31; 
charsv["@"] = 32; charsv["A"] = 33; charsv["B"] = 34; charsv["C"] = 35; 
charsv["D"] = 36; charsv["E"] = 37; charsv["F"] = 38; charsv["G"] = 39;
charsv["H"] = 40; charsv["I"] = 41; charsv["J"] = 42; charsv["K"] = 43; 
charsv["L"] = 44; charsv["M"] = 45; charsv["N"] = 46; charsv["O"] = 47; 
charsv["P"] = 48; charsv["Q"] = 49; charsv["R"] = 50; charsv["S"] = 51; 
charsv["T"] = 52; charsv["U"] = 53; charsv["V"] = 54; charsv["W"] = 55; 
charsv["X"] = 56; charsv["Y"] = 57; charsv["Z"] = 58; charsv["["] = 59; 
charsv["\\"] = 60; charsv["]"] = 61; charsv["^"] = 62; charsv["_"] = 63; 
charsv["`"] = 64; charsv["a"] = 65; charsv["b"] = 66; charsv["c"] = 67; 
charsv["d"] = 68; charsv["e"] = 69; charsv["f"] = 70; charsv["g"] = 71; 
charsv["h"] = 72; charsv["i"] = 73; charsv["j"] = 74; charsv["k"] = 75; 
charsv["l"] = 76; charsv["m"] = 77; charsv["n"] = 78; charsv["o"] = 79; 
charsv["p"] = 80; charsv["q"] = 81; charsv["r"] = 82; charsv["s"] = 83;  
charsv["t"] = 84; charsv["u"] = 85; charsv["v"] = 86; charsv["w"] = 87; 
charsv["x"] = 88; charsv["y"] = 89; charsv["z"] = 90; charsv["{"] = 91; 
charsv["|"] = 92; charsv["}"] = 93; charsv["~"] = 94; charsv["•"] = 99; 
charsv["š"] = 104; charsv["œ"] = 106;

var result = 'AaBbCc'.split('').map(function(char){
    return charsv[char];
});
console.log(result);
```